# iPad application strange behavior

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, video

I am working on a simple video player base application in which I have eight buttons, on click of that buttons video plays and when video playing complete the button image changed. if user close the video then button image will not change.

This small app is working perfect with me and when I send it to client it behave strange, like some buttons works and some of them can't.

How do I resolve it!

Comment: Are you testing on a real device, or only on the simulator?

Comment: @Caleb I am testing on Device ipad 1, ipad 2 and both have iOS 5.0 and iOS 6.1.2 respectively.. It working fine with me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with iPad. All buttons worked fine on simulator, but on the iPad they worked randomly.
I figured out that the gesture recognizer is very precise on `TouchUpInside` event. If you tap and move your finger even a millimeter the touch event is being canceled, as it thinks it's a swipe.
I solved it with a little hack, by removing `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` and writing my own method with `gestureRecognizer`.